# Странное поведение string-append в racket exe

Tags: exe, racket

Есть следующий код:

```
(define (mainloop)
  (define addr (ask "addr"))
  (let-values (((host rel) (split-host-rel addr)))
    (displayln host)
    (displayln rel)
    (displayln (string-append "POST " rel " HTTP/1.1\r\n")))
  (mainloop))

(define (ask question)
  (printf "~a: " question)
  (read-line))

(define (split-host-rel addr)
  (let ((parts (regexp-match*
                #rx"http://([^/]+?)(/.+)" addr
                #:match-select cdr)))
    (values (caar parts) (cadar parts))))

(mainloop)
```

На вход урл, на выходе три строки: хост, путь к файлу и строка хттп запроса, но не суть.
Вопрос в следующем - в repl все работает нормально, но если создать екзешник и запустить его - то на выходе какая-то херня. И я в упор не понимаю в чем причина, ведь код один и тот же...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Блин, я понял. read-line по дефолту считает последним символом в строке \n, таким образом на винде он считывает строку до комбинации \r\n, оставляя при этом \r в строке:(
То есть, моим решением будет заменить функцию (ask question) на такую:

```
(define (ask question)
  (printf "~a: " question)
  (read-line (current-input-port) 'any))
```